# Black Scholes PDE in forward log space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finance, stochastic-analysis

In BS world, we have the stock process in log space $dS_t=(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)dt+\sigma dW$. Let's say we want to price $f(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_{t,x}[h(S(T)]$. Using Feynman-Kac, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}

On the other hand, if we consider the forward process (again in log space) $F_t=S_t+r(T-t)$, we have the forward process $dF_t=-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 dt+\sigma dW$ and the price becomes $f(t,y)=\mathbb{E}_{t,y}[h(F(T)]$. Using F-K again, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}

Somehow I fail to transform the first PDE to the second by change of variable directly from $S_t$ to $F_t$. Since $y=x+r(T-t)$, by chain rule, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, i.e., the first order is the same and so as the second order. So I end up with
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}
which is obviously wrong and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Both equations are wrong because the price $f(t,x)$ is wrong. You should discount $h$ with $e^{-r(T-t)}$ and correctly apply Ito's formula (or Feynman-Kac). ***Hint*** : apply Ito to $f(t,S_t)e^{-rt}$ and use that this must be a martingale (has no $dW$-term).

Comment: BWT what is your $V$?

Comment: Finally understood what the question actually was. If you replace $V$ by $f$ your first PDE is correct in log stock space. To get the same PDE in log forward space you need to handle carefully the $\partial t$ derivative. Ali's answer is on point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$ f_{X}(t,x)=f_{Y}(t,y(t,x)) $$
where
$$ y(t,x)=x+r(T-t) $$
then
$$ \frac{\partial f_{X}}{\partial t}=
\frac{\partial f_{Y}}{\partial t} +
\frac{\partial f_{Y}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=
\frac{\partial f_{Y}}{\partial t} -
r\frac{\partial f_{Y}}{\partial y}. $$